# How to fix bug with php Interface? Also that create conflickt with zend 3

Tags: php

I many time found a bug with zend 3

in the current step, I know it because not works correct interfaces

```
<?php
interface a
{
    public function log($msg);
}

abstract class b{
    private $taeway;
        static function start(a $taeway){
            $this->taeway = $taeway;
        }
  }

b::start();
?>
```

it return for me

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to b::start() must
>   implement interface a, none given, called in
>   D:\Apache24\htdocs\Ihor\iofadsjd.php on line 12 and defined in
>   D:\Apache24\htdocs\Ihor\iofadsjd.php:8 
> Stack trace:
>  #0
>   D:\Apache24\htdocs\Ihor\iofadsjd.php(12): b::start()
>  #1 {main} thrown
>   in D:\Apache24\htdocs\Ihor\iofadsjd.php on line 8

also, test please on your machine, it works well?

Comment: You are not passing anything to the `::start()` method, but it expects an object implementing that interface. Did you forget some more sample code here? What does this have to do with ZF3 btw?

Comment: I did tutorial example
https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/
configured all what possible and work with it about 3 days 

I think not possible to example for Zend not work - But all time  have this error (I try to debug zend and found this)

in another case (if need pass something) how I can pass interface?

Comment: Thank you mario - you help me)
I check and found error)

not correct configured data  (but you pushed me in the right direction)